# The image displayed in the GUI moves down every time user selects a newone (Tkinter, Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using tkinter to make a simple GUI and implement a neural network that I trained. The problem is, every time the user uses the button to select a new image to make a prediction, the entire gui moves down. Here pictures of what's happening

[First image selected and predicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEH1P.png)

[Second image selected and predicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umcpR.png)

Here's my code:

```
class App:
    
    def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Detector de Melanomas")
        self.image = ""
        
        global model
        model = load_model(os.path.join('models', 'detectormelanomas-NuevasImagenesMelanoma2.h5'))
        window_width = 700
        window_height = 700
        # get the screen dimension
        screen_width = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.root.winfo_screenheight()

        # find the center point
        center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width / 2)
        center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height / 2)

        # set the position of the window to the center of the screen
        self.root.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')
        
        
        titulo = ttk.Label(self.root, text="Detector de Melanomas", font=("Arial Bold", 12))
        titulo.pack(anchor=CENTER)
        
        file_upload = ttk.Button(self.root, text="seleccione la imagen sospechosa",
                                 command=lambda: self.upload_file())
        file_upload.pack()

        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        
        

        # when loading a file in, root.lower()

    def run(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def upload_file(self):
        file_path = fd.askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('jpg files', '*.jpg'),
        ('jpeg files', '*.jpeg'),
        ('jpg files', '*.png'),
        ('All files', '*.*')])
        if file_path is not None:
            pass
        
        
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file_path.name))
        self.image = img

        output = tk.Label(self.root, text=file_path.name, image=self.image)
        output.pack()
        

        imagen = cv2.imread(file_path.name)
        imagen = tf.image.resize(imagen, (224,224), preserve_aspect_ratio=True)
        pred = model.predict(np.expand_dims(imagen/255, 0))
        pred_label = ""
        if pred > 0.5:
            print(f'La prediccion es Melanoma')
            pred_label = "La prediccion es Melanoma"
        else:
            print(f'La prediccion es Lunar')
            pred_label = "La prediccion es Lunar"
        prediccion = ttk.Label(self.root, text=pred_label, font=("Arial Bold", 12))
        prediccion.pack(anchor=CENTER)
new_app = App()
new_app.run()
```

Comment: Why *wouldn't* the contents move down the page?  You're doing absolutely NOTHING to remove the previous label and image.  (The only reason the old image turns blank is that you no longer have a reference to it, once you assign a new value to `self.image`.). Easiest fix would be to create the two Labels when the program starts, and just configure their image and text when a new image is loaded, rather than creating new widgets.

Comment: You were right. Thanks! I just used label.configure() and declared them first.